# Contents of the file is empty when stop button is clicked

Tags: java, android

My problem is that the file is empty after clicking stop button but only when the time changes e.g. when i click start button at 16:49:39 and then stop button at 16:49:57 then the file is empty. But when I click stop button 16:50:01 then the file saves with data.Please tell my why this  happens ? And how to solve this. Below you can see the code from my application:

OnClick code:

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.startButton:
            stoper.start();

            try {
                writer = new CSVwriter(dateFormat.format(date));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
            handler.postDelayed(UpdateView, 120);
            break;
        case R.id.stopButton:
            stoper.stop();

            try {
                writer.closeFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
            break;
    }
}

private Runnable UpdateView = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timerText.setText(stoper.toString());
        pulsText.setText(""+accelerationX);

        try {
             writer.insertLine(new DataObject(stoper.toString(), accelerationX, accelerationY, accelerationZ));
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        handler.postDelayed(UpdateView, 100);
        }
};
```

OnCreate code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View startBtn = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        View stopBtn = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        handler = new Handler();


    }
```

Comment: What did you find out running it in the debugger and stepping through the code?

Comment: I tried to debug the code, but I did not notice any thing that causes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried manually calling flush() if the writer has a flush() method? (Most file writing classes should have a flush() method unless CSVwriter is your own class.)

Manually flushing the stream may help.

EDIT: As a side note, does the stoper.stop() ever throw an error? If it does move it to after the file close in the finally block to ensure it is always called after the file has been flushed and closed.

Comment: CSVwriter is my class and the closeFile method has flusch() in it

Comment: I've made some researches and it appears that the problem is different. I have run the timer for 40seconds and in the file there are only 24 seconds saved. But I still don't know where is the problem. I tried to debug the code, but I did't notice any thing that causes this problem.

Comment: I have figure out what was wrong. The problem was with my CSV writer class. In the closeFile the codu should be in this order: this.myFile.flush();
      this.writer.close();
      this.myFile.close();